# Adding an HP printer to the Windows domain

Tags: networking, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

I am tired to add the printer driver to each network client machine in our Windows domain.local network.

Is it possible to add the printer to the Active Directory and avoid this?

Where do I find instructions for HP 2055 and Windows Server 2008 R2?

Thanks.

EDIT: The printer is connected to the router.

Comment: This question tells us you know nothing about Active Directory or printers. Please ask your System Administrator for assistance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have several options here.

1. [Use a GPO to deploy the printer to your clients](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722179%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).
2. [Write a script to deploy the printer to your clients](http://www.petri.co.il/forums/showthread.php?t=6352).
3. Combine `1` and `2`.  Use a GPO to kick off a logon script to map the printer.
4. [Set up a print server and share the printer(s) out](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753109%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).
5. [Set the printer up on any machine and share it.](http://www.techiwarehouse.com/engine/9aa10a93/How-to-Share-Printer-in-Windows-Server-2008-R2)
6. Tell your users they ca share documents electronically, and don't need to be printing their crap on tree corpses.

Probably other options too.

Comment: Wow, I thought that simply adding it to AD was enough...

Comment: system administration is not for the weak of heart.

Comment: @ItsGC: Definitely!